# $S = f^{-1}(\lambda)$ is non-empty. Is $\lambda$ is a regular value if and only if S is a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that the preimage $S = f^{-1}(\lambda)$ is non-empty. Is $\lambda$ is a regular value if and only if S is a regular surface?

I am concerned with the direction $S$ is a regular surface $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda$ is a regular value. I can construct a surface where the gradient will be zero (ie a flat plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where the function is the gradient going from $S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). That would mean that for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$ $df_p = 0$. However, the $\lambda$ that constructed this plane would not be a regular value.

Does this counterexample make sense?

Comment: Yes, if you can construct that (and that indeed can be constructed), than that would be a counterexample